# Using Python requests instead of urllib3

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I have this code for sending queries to the TinEye API:

```
from PIL import Image
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac, io, requests, string, urllib, urllib3

path = '/home/some/file.jpg'
limit = 10

TINEYE_API_URL = 'http://api.tineye.com/rest/search/'
TINEYE_PUBLIC_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
TINEYE_SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

img = Image.open(path)
img.thumbnail((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image_data = io.BytesIO()
img.save(image_data, img.format == 'PNG' and 'PNG' or 'JPEG', optimize=1, quality=88)

t = int(time.time())
nonce = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10)) # 8+ random characters
boundary = '--%s--' % nonce
to_sign = TINEYE_SECRET_KEY + 'POST' + 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary + 'image_data' + str(t) + nonce + TINEYE_API_URL + 'limit=%s' % limit
data = { 'api_key': TINEYE_PUBLIC_KEY, 'date': t, 'nonce': nonce, 'api_sig': hmac.new(TINEYE_SECRET_KEY, to_sign, sha1).hexdigest(), 'limit': limit }
r = urllib3.connection_from_url(TINEYE_API_URL).request_encode_body('POST', TINEYE_API_URL+'?'+ urllib.urlencode(data), fields={'image_upload': ('image_data', image_data.getvalue())}, multipart_boundary=boundary, timeout=5)
print r.data
```

I usually prefer the Python requests library.  But I don't know  how to write the `urllib3.connection_from_url` part with the requests lib. Is that possible?

That's what I have, but it's not working:

```
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=' + boundary }
r = requests.post(TINEYE_API_URL, data=data, files={ 'image_data': image_data.getvalue() }, headers=headers, timeout=5)
print r.text
```

Comment: The `connection_from_url` method returns a `ConnectionPool`. From your example it's not clear that you need this.

Comment: No, I don't. It can be a simple one time connection.

Comment: You probably want [`requests.post`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests). Note that `requests` uses `urllib3`.

Comment: You can also use `random.choices(seq, k=10)` to build your nonce.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the vendors `pytineye` client? [Their examples](https://api.tineye.com/python/docs/) seems to cover exactly what you need.

Comment: I know that I can use `requests.post`. But there are parameter which I don't know how to use with requests. @Eric: Why should I use an extra package for a few lines of code? The above code does work. That is not an issue.

Comment: I've added the requests part that is rather obvious. But something is amiss. Something about the custom boundary.